# Why is a Ladybug called a פרת משה רבינו?

Tags: hebrew, animals, midrash, moshe-rabbeinu

I know people might consider this a Hebrew language question, but I decided it would be relevent because I'm wondering why a ladybug is called a פרת משה רבינו in Modern Hebrew. To the best of my knowledge, פרת is the Euphrates River, and adding Moshe Rabbeinu's name doesn't make that make any more sense. "Euphrates Moshe Rabbeinu"? How does that make any sense? Is there some Medrash or other Jewish source that might elude to the reason a ladybug is called this?

Comment: "Parat" means "cow of".

Comment: http://davidson.weizmann.ac.il/online/askexpert/general_know/%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A2-%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%94-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9D-%D7%96%D7%94-%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9F

Comment: It is a literal translation of the yiddish name for the lady bug, moshe rabeynu's beheymele.

Comment: http://forward.com/articles/5541/the-adorable-moses-cow/

Comment: This still looks like a strictly language question. On the same idea as to why the triangular shaped cookies eaten on Purim are called, in Hebrew, "Haman's ears". I thought only Vulcans have triangular ears.

Comment: @paquda - You ought to make that an answer; I would accept that one! Makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @DanF this question is asking whether this name originates in Judaism, which is a reasonable question, *ab initio*, as the name includes the phrase "Moshe Rabbeinu," which certainly comes from Judaism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to analysis from [here](http://www.haaretz.com/jewish/features/word-of-the-day-parat-moshe-rabbeinu-which-doesn-t-mean-moses-cow.premium-1.471262):

> On the way to explaining why the Hebrew term for ladybug is “parat
>   Moshe Rabbeinu” – the cow of Moshe Rabbeinu, meaning “Moses’ cow” –
>   Israeli linguist Reuven Merkin notes that quirky, affectionate and
>   religion-linked names for this insect are the norm in a variety of
>   languages.
>
> The Christian European names for the beetle turned into the Yiddish
>   equivalent of “Moses’ cow,” and the Hebrew version was taken directly
>   from the Yiddish, Merkin writes. But while I would have thought the
>   replacement was merely a way of excising the Christian influence on
>   the name and importing a Jewish one, Merkin speculates that Moses was
>   chosen because both the Jewish leader and the spotted beetle are
>   considered humble creatures who do no harm.